# Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$sql = "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '?'";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $database);
$stmt->execute();
$resultSet = $stmt->get_result();
```

It says "**Warning**: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in..."

Can somebody explain what's wrong? **$database** is a string.

Comment: You have to remove the single quotes around the question mark. It is not nessary in prepared statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `?` as a placeholder, don't use ticks `'` s

```
$sql = "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $database);
$stmt->execute();
$resultSet = $stmt->get_result();
```